# Method Session.getTimeZone is deprecated

Tags: google-apps-script

This Page:-- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics

I copied the code into the spreadsheet script editor.
When run advises me that:-
The method "Session.getTimeZone" has been marked as deprecated which means that the feature should be avoided and may be removed in the future. Consider using an alternative solution.

I have searched Google and http://www.w3schools.com/ and have not been able to find an Alternative... Please Advise...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
Session.getScriptTimeZone();
```

[Google Documentation - getScriptTimeZone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getscripttimezone)

`getScriptTimeZone()` does the exact same thing that `getTimeZone()` did.  There is no difference except for the name.